# Foreach values from array inside array

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

hi i need to get the values of a var that after making it a var_dump($var) i get:

```
array(1) {
    ["docs"]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> array(1) { 
            ["imgurl"]=> string(68) "http://xxxxx.com/demos/grider/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/22.jpg" } 
        [1]=> array(1) { 
            ["imgurl"]=> string(68) "http://xxxxx.com/demos/grider/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/33.jpg" } 
        [2]=> array(1) { 
            ["imgurl"]=> string(68) "http://xxxxx.com/demos/grider/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/22.jpg" } } }
```

I need to foreach the 2 img url strings starting with http://

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I can see 3 (not 2) "img url strings" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach($var['docs'] as $sub) {
    echo $sub['imgurl'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks MB; always missing those quotes.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it looks like you have not read the first sentence of the question.

Comment: Hi, this has worked perfect, but when i leave empty the fields i get Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0, in line where only is this code: $attachID = $var['docs'];

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arr['docs'] AS $key => $link) {
  echo $link['imgurl'].'<br />';
}
```